# awk to print selective lines matching regex in single expression

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Team,
I have specific lines to be printed.

output is below.

what i want is:

1 - whenever there is Rx where x=any number and R is alphabet R exists in first column of below output it should print me the $3 that is 3rd column.

2 - whenever there is no Rx in first column but M it should print column 2. so expected output is below

`Command> git diff HEAD~1 --name-status`

```
R063    src/services/jamoperator/events/BUILD.bazel    src/common/jam/operator/events/BUILD.bazel
R060    src/services/jamoperator/events/events.go      src/common/jam/operator/events/events.go
R100    src/services/jamoperator/events/events_test.go src/common/jam/operator/events/events_test.go
M       src/services/jamoperator/operator_test.go
R100    src/services/secrets/keys/keys.go       src/services/secrets/keys/keys.go1
M       src/services/secrets/main.go
```

expected output.

```
src/common/jam/operator/events/BUILD.bazel
src/common/jam/operator/events/events.go
src/common/jam/operator/events/events_test.go
src/services/jamoperator/operator_test.go
src/services/secrets/keys/keys.go1
src/services/secrets/main.go
```

i tried and got 1st part but want to assure is this the right way?
`git diff HEAD~1 --name-status | awk '$1 ~ /R./ { print $3}'`

also the second part like this
`git diff HEAD~1 --name-status | awk '$1 ~ /M/ { print $2}'`

so are both my approaches correct? is there a way I can build single expression?

Comment: Do you get your expected output with `git diff HEAD~1 --name-status | awk '$1 ~ /R./ { print $3} $1 ~ /M/ { print $2}'` ?

Comment: appreciate it. mark is as answer.

Comment: Already answered before ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Combining your two `awk` all in one:

```
git diff HEAD~1 --name-status | awk '$1 ~ /^R[0-9]/{print $3} $1 ~ /^M/{print $2}'
```

##### Decomposed:

```
git diff HEAD~1 --name-status |
    awk '
        $1 ~ /^R[0-9]/ {print $3}
        $1 ~ /^M/      {print $2}
    '
```

##### Output

```
src/common/jam/operator/events/BUILD.bazel
src/common/jam/operator/events/events.go
src/common/jam/operator/events/events_test.go
src/services/jamoperator/operator_test.go
src/services/secrets/keys/keys.go1
src/services/secrets/main.go
```

Comment: can you explain. how does your expression assure there will be digit after R? what if there is Rr or Rk?

Comment: @AhmFM : you never said you needed `Rr/Rk`

Answer (score 2):

Using `cat` to simulate the output from `git diff`, and tweaking OP's 2 code snippets into one:

```
$ cat git.out | awk '$1 ~ /^R/ { print $3 } $1 == "M" { print $2 }'
src/common/jam/operator/events/BUILD.bazel
src/common/jam/operator/events/events.go
src/common/jam/operator/events/events_test.go
src/services/jamoperator/operator_test.go
src/services/secrets/keys/keys.go1
src/services/secrets/main.go
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cat file` as a placeholder for your git command you can do this with any awk since your input always starts with R or M and therefore you don't need to test both:

```
$ cat file | awk '{print $(/^R/ ? 3 : 2)}'
src/common/jam/operator/events/BUILD.bazel
src/common/jam/operator/events/events.go
src/common/jam/operator/events/events_test.go
src/services/jamoperator/operator_test.go
src/services/secrets/keys/keys.go1
src/services/secrets/main.go
```